# loop through paginated API using python

Tags: python, api

i am trying to retrieve all the devices from the REST API below, but the API JSON response is limited to 10k rows. The code below only returns 40 rows, not sure why. How do i send multiple requests to retrieve all the devices to get past the 10k row limit?

https://developer.carbonblack.com/reference/carbon-black-cloud/platform/latest/devices-api/

n is the "num_found" from the json response which is retrieved from another python function and it's the total number of devices registered.

```
def getdevices(n):
    param = {
        "criteria": {"status": ["ACTIVE"], "target_priority": ["LOW", "MEDIUM", "HIGH", "MISSION_CRITICAL"]}
    }

    all_endpoints = []
    # loop through all  and return JSON object
    for start in range(0, n, 10001):
        r = requests.post(hostname+f'/appservices/v6/orgs/abcdefg/devices/_search?start={start}&rows=10000', data=json.dumps(param), headers=headers)
        if r.status_code != 200:
            logging.error('status code ' + str(r.status_code))
            logging.error('unable to get devices! ' + r.text)
            sys.exit(1)
        else:
            response = json.loads(r.text)
            r = response['results']
            for d in r:
                all_endpoints.append({k: d[k] for k in ("id", "registered_time", "last_contact_time",
                                                          "last_external_ip_address", "last_internal_ip_address",
                                                          "last_location", "login_user_name", "name")})
        return all_endpoints
```

Another example is the CURL command on the webpage below, how would I use a similar approach with python for the code above to retrieve all the devices?
https://community.carbonblack.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/Carbon-Black-Cloud-How-To-Use-API-Pagination/ta-p/40205

Thanks

Comment: It appears fromthe API documentation that the page size you are requesting is in `rows` and the start of page is in `start` - but as the default rows is 20 and you are requesting 10000 maybe you’re being too ambitious - servers are memory limited too, you know, so making large requests might cause problems:maybe you should use rows=20? Also you shouldn’t call sys.exit() when things go wrong: raise an exception is the Python way.

Comment: And the API says start+rows can’t exceed 10k rows, so why do you think you need to?